# Finding out the installed version of twig

Tags: php, twig

Is there a way to find out my installed version of Twig?

Something like

```
<p>The current version is {% twig.version %}</p>
```

(although I know that's not even close to being right).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try it:

```
<p>The current version is {{ constant('Twig_Environment::VERSION') }}</p>
```

Comment: outdated on twig 3 ! check ; https://stackoverflow.com/a/61833901/688689

Comment: Ironic paradox you need to know which version of Twig you have to know which code to use to find out which version of Twig you have. They should never have changed this!

Answer (score 30):

You will find it in `vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php`

```
/**
 * Stores the Twig configuration.
 *
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 */
class Twig_Environment
{
    const VERSION = '1.24.0';
```

**For later versions** of Twig, e.g. 2.7 onwards, you will find it at `/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php`

```
/**
 * Stores the Twig configuration.
 *
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 */
class Environment
{
    const VERSION = '2.9.0';
```

Comment: later, but better answer

Comment: I am very late here, but now it is moved to, from twig version 2.7, vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php

Answer (score 6):

For Twig 3, you need to use something like

```
`Twig version is {{ constant('\Twig\\Environment::VERSION') }}.`
```

inside your template.

Answer (score 3):

In your `composer.lock` file search for string `"name": "twig/twig"`

You'll see something like this:

```
        "name": "twig/twig",
        "version": "v3.3.9",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/twigphp/Twig.git",
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the version with Twig 3:

open `/vendor/twig/twig/CHANGELOG`