# I can't get twig to escape spec. html chars within <body>

Tags: html, escaping, twig

I did some research here and on the official Twig documentation, but couldn't find out whether the escaping is applied only on my runtime variables or also on that text that is originally in my templete files. I cannot get the latter to work.

So this is what I want to accomplish: I create a twig template file (let's say index.html) using some text editor, with a content like that:

```
...
{% autoescape 'html' %}
<body>this is some "text"</body>
{% endautoescape %}
...
```

And if I view the page source in the browser I want to see this:

```
...
<body>this is some &quot;text&quot;</body>
...
```

But insted I'm getting only this:

```
...
<body>this is some "text"</body>
...
```

The escaping doesn't seem to work for me. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of Twig are you using?

Comment: I can't find in which file it's in, however, in the CHANGELOG the last entry reads "* 1.18.2 (2015-06-06)", so I guess it's 1.18. (Anyways that's the second thing I don't understand. When you read the official documentation on the twig website, sometimes you see references to versions 1.8 and 1.9, while the latest stable is 1.19. Are they just some misspellings, and 1.8 and 1.9 actually mean 1.18 and 1.19?)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572725/finding-out-the-installed-version-of-twig) you can see how to get your Twig Version.

Comment: Yes, I also saw the 1.8 and 1.9 in the Docu. It must be a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% set strategy = 'html' %}

{% autoescape 'html' %}
    {{ var|escape(strategy)|raw }} {# won't be double-escaped #}
{% endautoescape %}
```